# Is there a way to pre-configure page settings in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

it's kinda tricky to quickly find something about this.

Is there a way I can pre-configure my page settings related to my theme in WordPress?

I guess maybe through Functions.php something is possible but I didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance.